# How do I get my ionic side menu button working?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

I recently tried creating an ionic side menu. I had a problem where when I swiped the main body it opened up the menu. But I took the swipe function off and now I can't open the menu. I want to be able to click the navicon icon to be able to open the menu but don't know how to do it.

**Here is the JavaScript:**

```
.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicModal, Projects, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {


  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
```

**Here is the header code which contains the button:**

```
<body ng-app="todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <ion-side-menus>

  <!-- Center content -->
  <ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
  <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleLeft()">
  </button>
  <h1 class="title">{{activeProject.title}}</h1>
  <!-- New Task button-->
  <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="newTask()">
    <i class="icon ion-compose"></i>
  </button>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content scroll="false">
<td-cards class="theLabel" id="card" ng-repeat="task in activeProject.tasks">
<td-card class="card-{{card.index}}">
<h4 style="text-align:center"> {{task.title}}</h4>
</td-card>
</td-cards>
```

**Here is the menu content:**

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">

      <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
           <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
               <h1 class="title">Cards</h1>
           </ion-header-bar>
           <ion-content scroll="true">
           <edge-drag-threshold="true" drag-content="true">
           </ion-content>
       </ion-pane> 

   </ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: Can you create a CodePen showing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic has a handy `menu-toggle` directive to use so you can toggle the menu on a button like this.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/menuToggle/

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
  <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
  </button>
  <h1 class="title">{{activeProject.title}}</h1>
  <!-- New Task button-->
  <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="newTask()">
    <i class="icon ion-compose"></i>
  </button>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Comment: This still doesn't open... do I need to change anything in the Javascript or the in the menu content code?

Comment: Without the full code or a demo to show the issue, its hard to know exactly. It should be working, but something else must be going on which isn't shown.

Comment: But what if you want to open side menu when the user click the hardware back button?

Comment: Use the $ionicPlatform http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/ feature to listen for the hardware back button, and then use $ionSideMenuDelegate http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSideMenuDelegate/ to toggle the menu.

Answer (score 2):

In index.html, replace `menu-toggle="left"` with `ng-click="toggleProjects()"` and in app.js add this

```
$scope.toggleProjects = function() {
  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
  <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleSideMenu()">
    <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
  </button>
  <h1 class="title">{{ activeProject.title }}</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
```

In **app.js**, check with `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpen()`

```
$scope.toggleSideMenu = function() {
  if ($ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpen()) {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(false); // close
  } else {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(); // open
  }
};
```

Comment: Helped, I needed to check if the side menu was opened because I wanted to close it when switching to a new tab :)